# Which exact processor model do the macbook pros have?

Tags: macbook-pro

The new 15 and 17 inch macbook pros only list the processor model as quad-core core i7.
However what is the fully model number of the processor?
Are the quad core processors really dual cores with hyperthreading or are they really quad core? 
Do any of the models have hyperthreading?

As requested pasting info about the macbook pro model to enhance this page:

Model Name:   MacBook Pro

Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,2

Processor Name:   Intel Core i7

Processor Speed:  2 GHz

Number of Processors: 1

Total Number of Cores:    4

L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB

L3 Cache: 6 MB

Memory:   4 GB

Boot ROM Version: MBP81.0047.B04

Comment: Please specify which generation; people may see this in the future when it isn't so clear.

Comment: i dont know where to find the 'generation' number for the current macbook pros.

Comment: It's in System Profiler, on the first page that shows up on launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processor used in the early 2011 15" and 17" i7 models is the 2.2 GHz quad-core (2720QM) Intel Core i7 Sandy Bridge with 6 MB on-chip L3 cache, so they have 4 cores and 8 threads.

Apple's [MacBook Pro performance](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/performance.html) page makes it clear that Hyper-Threading is now standard on all MacBook Pro laptops.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the model number, but they are actually quad core with hyperthreading, giving 8 logical cores.

Answer (score 0):

Although Apple very rarely prints exact CPU model numbers, a good reference site is [EveryMac](https://everymac.com) - it contains a database of all Macs, including exact CPU model numbers.